# Attach Google Docs to a gmail message

Tags: gmail, google-drive

I can only link and not attach Google Docs.

So, if the recipient does not have Google Drive, I have to download a converted document and upload it again.
This is very time consuming and inefficient.

How can I send immediately a converted version of a document?
Can the conversion be executed in the cloud (without downloading/uploading)?
This is what already happens from docx to gdoc, when editing a docx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but the recipient can download the document as docx without a Google account by opening the document and doing the steps shown in this image:[image]

For this to work the document has to a 'shared to anyone with the link'. When testing this out, gmail automatically reminded me to do this when attaching the Drive document.

Comment: Unless the file is very large, it does not seem more convenient than download-upload. But the real problem is that I cannot assume that the recipient is knowledgeable about gdocs, and can't type the directions for every mail attachment.

Answer (score 0):

The recipient can follow the link and download the file to whatever format he or she desires.

Go to File > Download As > select File format.

[image]